# React- Strange output while passing an id to back-end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this project for a perfume store.
I have this `CARD` component of a perfume.

Basically I would like the user to click on the card and render a new component with full details of card.
So, for that I pass via path an id parameter.

```
 {
                            state.map(c => (
                                <Grid  item xs={4} sm={2} >
                                    <PerfumeCard key={c.id} perfume={c} />
                                    <button className="myButton2">  <NavLink
                                        style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
                                        to={{
                                            pathname: '/home/myperfume/' + c.id,
                                          
                                            
                                            }}>
                                        Click here for details
                                    </NavLink></button>
                                </Grid>
                            ))
                        }
```

so far I have no issues.
on my `CARD DETAILS` component I use `useParams()` in order to fetch the id so I can save in the state the perfume since I am using a `Redux` store.

```
 const params = useParams()
    const id = params.id;
    const [state, setState] = useState<any>('');
```

**and fetching the `object`:**

```
setState(store.getState().perfumeState.perfumes[id]);
```

Now when I check my `console` for debugging I see that when I use `console.log` it shows the correct ID, however, when I `console.log` the actual state saved while passing the `ID` I get a different object with a different ID.

lets say I click on card with id `1`.

Console.log(id) = `1`;

console.log(state) =
`MyPerfume.tsx:29 {id: 2, name: 'Green Irish Tweed', type: 'EDT', gender: 'UNISEX', season: 'SUMMER', …}`

as you can see I get returned the object of id `2` for some reason

and when I press card with ID `2` I get returned the object with ID `5` for example.

what causes this Behavior? I could not seem to get my hands on the problem, however, I know I am missing somthing.

is there a better way in which I could fetch the object without this issue?

Still new to this.

Thanks!

Comment: The state is an array?

Comment: With `perfumes[id]` you take the i-th element in the array. For example if you write `perfumes[1]` you take the second element inside the array and **not** the element with id 1

Answer (score 0):

`store.getState().perfumeState.perfumes[id]` doesn't mean it will send the `perfume` with `id=1`, it will send the `perfume` in the position `1` of the `perfumes` array, that's why is different on the server, try to use a `array.find`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Hi. I tried using your suggestion (state holds array of objects) ` const found = state.find(x => x.id === id);` How ever when I log it, I get undefiend. is my syntax ok?

Comment: It looks correct, can you post an example using codesandbox to debug it better?